# Why the c++ function can return array’s size correctly?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, constexpr

I was learning c++11 about constexpr.
So I went to website and learnt how to code it.  When I was learning how to code it.  I had raised a problem about return array’s size function.  I thought it was functional, but I couldn’t know how write it like this.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto newline = "\n";

template < typename Type , uint32_t SZ>
constexpr uint32_t len(const Type (&array)[SZ])
{
    return SZ;
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr = new int (9);
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,*ptr};
    std::cout << len(array) << newline;
}
/*
Output:
6

*/
```

I want to know why len function return array‘s size correctly.

Comment: Are you asking how this particular snippet deduces the array length? And how this information is passed back to the caller? Or what?

Comment: What do you mean 'why'? Why not? The compiler is written that way that is compiles to a code which gives the proper answer.

Comment: Note that the appropriate type for `SZ` is `std::size_t`. `std::uint32_t` might be the same as `std::size_t`, but that's not required, and sometimes it's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The array has type `int[6]` (I know you omitted the `[6]` in the declaration, but this is still true)

  - Notice that the size is part of the type
- Passing an array by reference prevents decay to a pointer

  - The reference type is `int (&)[6]` (you've added a `const` for good measure)
- The function is actually a template, taking `const T (&)[N]` where both `T` and `N` are parameters

  - Template calls like this can *deduce* template parameters, so `N` is detected automatically!
  - You could also have called `len<int, 6>(array)`, but that's even more pointless…
- The value of `N` is then returned from the function as a simple number.

`N` should be a `std::size_t`, though, not a `std::uint32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

`SZ` is a template argument. The compiler knows what argument was used to instantiate the template.

The argument doesn't need to be specified explicitly, because it can be deduced from the type of non-template argument `array`. The type of the argument expression is `int[6]`. Note that the size of the array is part of the type of the array.

For further learning, I recommend studying the topic "template argument deduction".